# Django page stuck on loading when click on reload page.

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I build a web app with django what process image on background. When I start the server load the page first time it works perfectly and save the image on folder. But the problem is  when I click on the refresh button of browser it stuck on loading. I try to close sever I see that the server(ctrl+x) it closes but i see that it is running on background. After restarting the server again the app works for the first time but again stuck on loading if I click the refresh button. I want that if I click on the refresh button of the browser the app will run from the beginning.  I don't know what is the problem with code. I an new to django please give me hint what to do. My operating system is linux and using python 2.7.

the code of views.py is given bellow: -

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import numpy as np
import cv2
import Image
from PIL import Image
import ctypes
import os
import ImageDraw

#
#
#
#
#

def index(request):
    im_gray = cv2.imread('Rimage.jpg', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
    (thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY |  cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    thresh = 100
    im_bw = cv2.threshold(im_gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    cv2.imwrite('bw_image.png', im_bw)
    im = cv2.imread('bw_image.png')
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
    thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,1,1,19,4)
    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    h_list=[]
    for cnt in contours:
        [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        if w*h>250:
            h_list.append([x,y,w,h])
    ziped_list=zip(*h_list)
    x_list=list(ziped_list[0])
    dic=dict(zip(x_list,h_list))
    x_list.sort()
    i=0
    for x in x_list:
        [x,y,w,h]=dic[x]
        im3=im[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        cv2.imwrite('objects/pix%i.png'%i,im3)
        i+=1
    cv2.imwrite('objects/shhh.jpg',im)
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    im0 = cv2.imread('objects/pix0.png',0)
    im1 = cv2.imread('objects/pix1.png',0)
    im2 = cv2.imread('objects/pix2.png',0)
    im3 = cv2.imread('objects/pix3.png',0)
    im4 = cv2.imread('objects/pix4.png',0)
    im5 = cv2.imread('objects/pix5.png',0)

    h0, w0 = im0.shape[:2]
    h1, w1 = im1.shape[:2]
    h2, w2 = im2.shape[:2]
    h3, w3 = im3.shape[:2]
    h4, w4 = im4.shape[:2]
    h5, w5 = im5.shape[:2]
    maxh=max(h0,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5)

    new = np.zeros((maxh,w0+w1+w2+w3+w4+w5+50),np.uint8)
    new=(255-new)
    new[maxh-h0:, :w0] = im0
    new[maxh-h1:, w0+10:w0+w1+10] = im1
    new[maxh-h2:, w0+w1+20:w0+w1+w2+20] = im2
    new[maxh-h3:, w0+w1+w2+30:w0+w1+w2+w3+30] = im3
    new[maxh-h4:, w0+w1+w2+w3+40:w0+w1+w2+w3+w4+40] = im4
    new[maxh-h5:, w0+w1+w2+w3+w4+50:] = im5
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(new, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    cv2.imwrite('new_image.jpg',gray)
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)

#resize image..........................................
    im22 = Image.open("new_image.jpg")
    img22 = im22.resize( (157,57), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img22.save("new_image1.jpg", dpi=(1200,1200) )
#image with white background........................... 
    img1 = Image.open("new_image1.jpg")
    img2 = img1.crop( (0,-34,600,566) )
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img2)
    draw.rectangle( (0,0,600,34), fill="white" )
    draw.rectangle( (0,90,600,600), fill="white" )
    draw.rectangle( (157,0,600,600), fill="white" )
    img2.save("img2.jpg","JPEG", quality=90)
#remove files.....................................................
    os.remove('bw_image.png')
    os.remove('img2.jpg')
    os.remove('new_image.jpg')
    os.remove('new_image1.jpg')
    os.remove('objects/pix0.png')
    os.remove('objects/pix1.png')
    os.remove('objects/pix2.png')
    os.remove('objects/pix3.png')
    os.remove('objects/pix4.png')
    os.remove('objects/pix5.png')
    os.remove('objects/shhh.jpg')
#end..........................................................

    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Reasons of your problem might not be obvious, you should try to use 'print-technique' to locate problem.
The point is that you should put print everywhere, like this

```
def index(request):
    im_gray = cv2.imread('Rimage.jpg', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
    print 'after im_gray'
    (thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY |     cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    print 'after (thresh, im_bw)'
    thresh = 100
    print 'after thresh'
    im_bw = cv2.threshold(im_gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    print 'after im_bw'
```

And so on. Then you just open terminal, run your django project and check what print is last, obviously reason of your app broke down will be next line after last print in terminal.
That approach may seem sloppy and probably my answer will be dropped down by experienced python guru but it works and works very good. Just try it and you will figure out your problem in minutes.